# How to separate Bot's from members in member_count?

Tags: python, bots, discord, python-3.7

During a command that displays the member count of the server, i'd like to separate the number of bots from the number of human members and display them each. I can output the total number of members in the server but i'm not sure how to get the bot to distinguish a bot user from human user.

```
if message.content.startswith('<count'):
        channel = message.channel
        members = message.guild.member_count
        msg = discord.Embed(title="Amount of members in this Discord:", description=members, color=0x0000ff)
        await channel.send(embed=msg)
```

How would I separate the bot users from the count and display that number separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't really find anything specific in the Discordpy documentation that allows fetching of members.
So I decided to get the entire list of members in the server instead and filter the list by bots.

```
if message.content.startswith('<count'):    
        membersInServer = message.guild.members
        # Filter to the list, returns a list of bot-members
        botsInServer = list(filter(filterOnlyBots, membersInServer))

        botsInServerCount = len(botsInServer)
        # (Total Member count - bot count) = Total user count
        usersInServerCount = message.guild.member_count - botsInServerCount

        # Whatever you want to do with the count here

# Put this function somewhere...
# Filter the member list to only bots
def filterOnlyBots(member):
    return member.bot
```

Speed/performance might be a downside as the server gets larger (more members), hopefully someone posts a better solution than mine.

Comment: for that I get `botsInServerCount = len(botsInServer)
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`

Comment: @BrandonWeeks fixed the answer. I forgot that filter() does not return a list. I converted that to a list after it was done filtering

Comment: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'filterOnlyBots' was never awaited
  botsInServer = list(filter(filterOnlyBots, membersInServer))` and then it returns the entire member count, bots and all

Comment: @BrandonWeeks I am not so sure about this issue since I am pretty sure none of the functions I used was a Coroutine. Which version of Discordpy are you using?

Comment: Says I’m using 1.2.3

Comment: Unfortunately I have not much clue on why the warning appears. I am currently using Discordpy 1.3.0a and there is no issues on my side. Hopefully someone else can help you with this issue

Comment: Any way I could upgrade my discord.py? If so, would that potentially break the bot?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#installing I recommend refering to the documentation whenever you need to do something API-related and have issues with it. As for breaking the bot, the version looks similar, so I would say you at most have to do minor changes

Comment: I've tried that and this was the result: `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
Requirement already up-to-date: discord.py in c:\users\ste4l\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.2.3).`
Im looking at this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Discord.InteractivityAddon/#
would that overwrite the current version? Ive been combing through the API the past week trying to learn this, it just gets confusing at times.

Comment: I got it working. Not sure how but it does work with this version. Thank you for your time, very appreciated!!!